# Azure SQLDatabase Security - Cannot delete Dynamic Data Masking Rule from Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-masking, azure-security

I am trying to delete a Dynamic Data Masking Rule on Azure SQLDatabase form the portal, the portal says that the Rule got deleted successfully, but when i refresh the page, the rule is still there. Couple of my colleagues also ran into the same issue.

Is this a bug/quirk from the portal, or are we doing something wrong? Is there any other way to get this working (portal, powershell, cli)?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. I just created a mask of credit card type, then I deleted it, I then went to other sections on the portal, when I returned to the Dynamic Masking Rule page the rule was not there. It was deleted for good. Do you have steps to reproduce this behavior that I can share with related Microsoft team?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Steps performed were 1) Enable Dynamic Data Masking from the Azure Portal 2) From SQL Server Management Studio, try to encrypt the column that was masked. I get a warning saying encryption not allowed if the column is masked already. 3) From the portal, i delete the masking rule. Portal shows the successfully deleted message, but when i come back and refresh, the masking rule is still there 4) In the SQL Server Mgmt Studio, it still doesn't allow me to encrypt the column.

Comment: Thank you.Hope PowerShell does the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the behavior with Dynamic Masking Rules on the portal but as a workaround you can try using PowerShell to remove the rule:

```
Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabaseDataMaskingRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"
 -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01" -SchemaName "dbo"
 -TableName  "table1" -ColumnName "column1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to encounter this issue, please open a support ticket with all the details (subscription, server, database) and we can investigate why this is happening. The mask should be successfully removed when you delete it - there aren't any known bugs in this area.